# Disable faction claiming and mcmmo party tping

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

I'm on a Minecraft server where I don't have access to server folders but I want to disable faction claiming and McMMO party tping. I have group manager to manage the perms. I have tried denying access the to perm by doing `-mcmmo.commands.ptp` (not sure if that is how you deny access to a command) but it didn't work.

Anyone got way to do this? (Please do not say install this plugin and also once again I do not have access to server files so a way to do this without the server files is what I'm looking for)

Comment: Are you an admin of this server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you want to do, you need to do what you have already done, but there is a small change you need to make:

1. For the party tp, you cannot allow users any '*' permissions that are related to it, for example 'mcmmo.*' or 'mcmmo.commands.*', as removing nodes with -[permission-node] will most likely not work. Secondly, the user cannot be opped. With most plugins, OPs are allowed all permissions by default. (I am presuming that you are either using '*' permissions or trying it with an opped player)
2. For the factions claiming, same thing, but with the 'factions.claim' permission node, so the line would look like this:

   - -factions.claim

   And for the mcmmo:

   - -mcmmo.commands.ptp

Hope this helped!